# What type do I use in the constructor to initialize a member variable defined by a nameless enum?

Tags: c++, struct, enums, unions

I have a struct containing a member variable `category` which I guess is of type "nameless enum".

```
struct Token {
    Token();
    enum {
            NUMBER, VARIABLE, PLUS, MINUS, PRODUCT, DIVISION, POWER, SIN, COS
    } category;
    union { 
        char variable;
        double number;
    };
};
```

As you can see I also have a constructor `Token()`. I would like to be able to use the constructor like this:

```
Token my_token(Token::NUMBER, 5);
```

Instead of doing something like this:

```
Token my_token;
my_token.category = Token::NUMBER;
my_token.number = 5;
```

My question now is, what types do I use for the constructor? I tried something like this:

```
//declaration
Token(int category, int number);

//definition
Token(int category, int number) : category(category), number(number) {}
```

But then when I try to initialize an object of the Token struct I get:
`error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘Token::<unnamed enum>’ [-fpermissive]`

I would like to keep the enum inside of the struct, some help with what type to use to initialize the union would also be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to give the enum type a type name?

Comment: @Eljay No, the answer MatG gave me worked for me! Which was giving the enum a name then using that name as type in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
struct Token {
    enum EN {
            NUMBER, VARIABLE, PLUS, MINUS, PRODUCT, DIVISION, POWER, SIN, COS
    } category;
    union { 
        char variable;
        double number;
    };
    Token(const EN c, const double n) noexcept : category(c), number(n) {}
    //... Other constructors...
};

int main()
{
    Token t(Token::NUMBER, 3.4);
}
```

But I'd assign the category internally